# Need to make a something like a tool tip with a literal inside

Tags: asp.net

I'm tring to basically make a box appear when ever someone hovers over a button like a tool tip. But i want to be able to put html inside the box. I have been able to do this with a div and some javascript to hide and unhide the div but I cant seem to make the div appear where the mouse is when it is over the button. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: could you elaborate some more and share some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get help using a library like jquery.

Or you can try with something like:

http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create_lightweight_javascript_tooltip/

Here is a working demo:

http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tooltip/

You need to replace the logic to work with your button, but it should be easy.